# Get a proper x and width if there is only total width exist and array of some coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

A question about an enhancement part.

I have a chart and behind the chart I want to have stripes to cover entire background.
On the chart there are vertical lines that should visually divide the stripes.

So I have the next data: 
1) the total width of the canvas, assume it 600
2) the Array with x coordinated on the canvas, assume there is something like `[100,250,300,600]`

I need to get the width and next point for each stripe. I can generate them by the following code:

```
let linesArray = [100,250,300,500]; 
linesArray.unshift(0);
let totalWidth = 500;
let stripes = linesArray.map((x, i) => {
let width = (i === 0) ? linesArray[i+1] : linesArray[i+1] !== undefined ? linesArray[i+1] - x : totalWidth - x;

return <rect x={x} width={width }></rect>
})
```

But to be true I don't like how this looks like, maybe there is some better solution to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a small error in it. In the expression `width - x` in line 5, you are probably thinking of the total width of the background. Let's call that `totalWidth`. Then your code can be:

```
let totalWidth = 1000;

let linesArray = [100,250,300,500]; 
linesArray.unshift(0);

let stripes = linesArray.map((x, i) => {
    let width = linesArray[i+1] ? linesArray[i+1] - x - 1 : totalWidth - x;

    return <rect x={x} width={width}></rect>
})
```

EDIT: Added - 1 to make sure stripes are not overlapping

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot to specify this variable in the example. 
and yes, your code is working, each stripe just overwrites the previous line by the width so I can also specify the color for the stripe and it will work, great 
thanks

Comment: If you like it, please accept it as the correct answer ;) @ConstantineGolub

Comment: ok, it's a good short alternative solution but there is one downside of it. If I add opacity to the lines it doesn't work properly because the line next to other line overlap and colors mixed. In any case, I like your version! ;)

Comment: Ah, you are right! They do overlap. I changed the code by subtracting 1 from the length of the inner stripes. They should not overlap now. @ConstantineGolub